# what is the conversion form of jade to ejs

Tags: pug, ejs

I am having a problem to convert the following jade lang to EJS.

```
div.error
 if errors
  each error, i in errors
   li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
```

Would someone please help me out?

Comment: This question would be better rephrased without the pug aspect and only with the desired HTML output instead.  That will make it easier for EJS experts to help you, which is I believe what you want.

Comment: @Graham That would make it harder to help with converting Pug conditional and loop syntax to the EJS equivalent

Comment: This is very simple syntax that could be described in plain language.  I'm sure you could write a short paragraph to describe what is wanted and the desired HTML code.